# HTML doesn't update properly on child element after sorting an array of items on parent component when using updated()

Tags: html, typescript, lit-element, lit-html, lit

I am sorting an array of so called 'activities' in my customElement using LitElement:

```
    @property({ type: Array }) private activityListLocal: Array<Activity> = [];
```

in the parent customElement called "find-activity".

Each activity is being rendered here.

```
    ${repeat(
          this.activityListLocal,
          activity =>
            html` <div class="activity-container">
              <div class="activity">
                <activity-info .activity=${activity}></activity-info>
              </div>
              <div class="activity" class="rating">
                <activity-rating
                  .activity=${activity}
                  @appactivityremoveclick=${() => this.deleteActivity(activity)}
                ></activity-rating>
              </div>
            </div>`
        )}
```

This is how it looks visually:
[2 activities marked for some impression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogEOi.png)

On clicking the button "Highest Rating", I am sorting the list of activities:

```
sortActivityListLocal() {
    this.activityListLocal = [...this.activityList];
    this.activityListLocal = this.activityListLocal.sort((a, b) => (a.avgRating < b.avgRating ? 1 : -1));
  }
if (category === 'all') {
      this.activityListLocal = this.activityList;
    } else if (category === 'Highest Rating') {
      this.sortActivityListLocal();
      if (this.activityListLocal.length === 0) {
        this.nothingHere.style.display = 'block';
      }
    }
    //....
}
```

Note: this.activityList is a local copy of the server response.

In the image, you see the two sliders, which should be updated to move with the activity if the position on the page changes. The issue: The "my rating" slider does not properly "move" with the activity, if it has been changed/dragged after the page has been loaded for the first time.
Before:
[Activities are loaded in properly, cinema has a higher rating than Tennis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAifM.png)
After:
[Activities are sorted properly, all sliders are correctly "moved" if "myRating" has not been changed/dragged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXp5p.png)

But if the slider was dragged after inital load in, and then selecting the "highest rating" category and therefore sorting the array, it stays in place:

Before:
[After loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9z2P.png)
Dragging the slider (not even requesting an update with a click on the refresh icon, issue happening in both cases)
[Modification leading to the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwCV2.png)
After:
[Issue visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y97Xe.png)

The interesting thing, the slider has the correct! value in the html inspector, but the display is not showing it. Why is this happening?

Code of the component holding the sliders:

```
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit';
import { customElement, property, query } from 'lit/decorators.js';
import { httpClient } from '../../../http-client';
import { PageMixin } from '../../page.mixin';
import { Activity, Rating } from '../find-activity';
import componentStyle from './activity-rating.css';
@customElement('activity-rating')
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
class ActivityRatingComponent extends PageMixin(LitElement) {
  static styles = componentStyle;

  @property({ reflect: true }) activity = {} as Activity;
  @property() rating = {} as Rating;
  @query('#deleteButton') private deleteButton!: HTMLImageElement;

  private currentSliderValue = -1;

  async updated() {
    console.log(
      `Personal rating for ${this.activity.title} is ${this.activity.personalRating}, avgRating ${this.activity.avgRating}, currentSliderValue ${this.currentSliderValue}`
    );
    this.currentSliderValue = this.activity.personalRating ? this.activity.personalRating : 0;
    console.log(`Current slider value after: ${this.currentSliderValue}`);

    if (this.activity.deletepermission === false) this.deleteButton.style.display =     'none';
    else this.deleteButton.style.display = 'inline';
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      ${this.renderNotification()}
      <div class="outer-rating">
        <p>${this.activity.motivationtitle}</p>
        <div class="slidecontainer">
          <label for="overallRating">Overall Rating</label>
          <input
            type="range"
            min="0"
            max="100"
            value=${this.activity.avgRating ? this.activity.avgRating : 0}
            class="slider"
            id="overallRating"
            disabled
          />
        </div>
        <div class="slidecontainer">
          <label for="myRating">My Rating</label>
          <input
            type="range"
            min="0"
            max="100"
            value=${this.activity.personalRating ? this.activity.personalRating : '0'}
            class="slider"
            id="myRating"
            @change="${(e: Event) => this.readcurrentSliderValue(e)}"
          />
          <img id="personalSlider" src="/refresh.png" alt="update" @click=${this.savecurrentSliderValueToDb} />
          <img
            class="remove-task"
            src="/deleteicon.png"
            alt="update"
            id="deleteButton"
            @click="${this.confirmDelete}"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    `;
  }

  confirmDelete(e: Event) {
    const target = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
    if (target) {
      const result = confirm('Want to delete?');
      if (result) {
        this.emit('appactivityremoveclick');
      }
    }
  }

  readcurrentSliderValue(e: Event) {
    const target = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
    if (e) {
      this.currentSliderValue = Number(target?.value);
      console.log('Read new slider value ' + Number(target?.value));
    }
  }

  async savecurrentSliderValueToDb() {
    const partialRating: Partial<Rating> = {
      activityid: this.activity.id,
      rating: Number(this.currentSliderValue) //userID is not included here as it is being provided by the auth Middleware on patch request.
    };
    await httpClient.patch(`rating/${this.activity.id}${location.search}`, partialRating);

    const responseRatingAll = await httpClient.get(`rating/findAverageRating/${this.activity.id}` + location.search);
    try {
      this.activity.avgRating = (await responseRatingAll.json()).results;
      this.activity.personalRating = partialRating.rating ? partialRating.rating : 0;
    } catch (error) {
      this.showNotification((error as Error).message, 'error');
    }
    this.requestUpdate();
  }

  emit(eventType: string, eventData = {}) {
    const event = new CustomEvent(eventType, {
      detail: eventData,
      bubbles: true,
      composed: true
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
}
```

[Visual confirmation that slider has the correct value, but doesn't show it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaD3u.png)

Thank you :)

Comment: Does binding the input elements `value` property resolve the issue (Note period: `.value`)? I.e. 
`<input .value=${this.activity.avgRating ? this.activity.avgRating : 0}  />`

Also see the following reference about [the input element](https://github.com/lit/lit/issues/2818#issuecomment-1158116319).

Comment: That was very helpful. It now works as intended. Thank you! @YouCodeThings

Comment: Hi, could you please mark the answer as correct if it helped so this question is marked answered. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: In addition to the answer below - specifically for the case where "you want to force a value to be set on an element". Lit has an optimization where "if a value hasn't changed, don't do anything". Rendering the same value to an expression will not cause the expression to update. To make sure Lit updates the expression if the underlying DOM value has changed use the [`live`](https://lit.dev/docs/templates/directives/#live) directive.

The native browser `input` elements default behavior is:

- When the value attribute is changed, update the input elements value property.
- After a manual user interaction (such as typing into the input element if it is a text input), the `value` attribute no longer updates the input property.
- After the `value` property has been updated the attribute no longer causes the property to update.

Therefore by setting the `value` property the value updates.

Because of that browser behavior, in Lit you can use a [`property expression`](https://lit.dev/docs/templates/expressions/#property-expressions) to set the `value` property.

I.e.: `<input .value=${this.activity.avgRating ? this.activity.avgRating : 0}`.

Below is an example of the browser input behavior. Click the two buttons. One will update the `value` attribute, the other the `value` property.
Then interact with the input. Type in it. Now the attribute button will stop working.

```js
const inputEl = document.querySelector('input')
const getRandomValue = () => String(Math.random()).slice(0, 5)

document.querySelector("#btn-attr")
  .addEventListener("click", () => {
    inputEl.setAttribute('value', getRandomValue())
  });

document.querySelector("#btn-prop")
  .addEventListener("click", () => {
    inputEl.value = getRandomValue()
  });
```

```html
<input value="12345">

<button id="btn-attr">Change input attribute</button>
<button id="btn-prop">Change input property</button>
```